# JavaScript works for one id but not another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript file which essentially draws a line when the user scrolls down the page. It draws a line for the first SVG but not for the other (which uses the same class). For example, I have the following code block in both `text-repeater.php` **and** `text-block.php`:

```
<svg height="100" width="200">
   <line class="line__svg" id="line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200"  />
</svg>
```

And here is my `parallax.js` file:

```
var scrollLine = document.getElementById("line");
var length = scrollLine.getTotalLength();

// Start position of  drawing
scrollLine.style.strokeDasharray = length;

// Find scroll percentage on scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

    var draw = length * scrollpercent;

    // Reverse drawing (when scrolling upwards)
    scrollLine.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
}
```

The line draws in `text-block.php` but not in `text-repeater.php`

Ideas why?

Also, on a related note. How can I get the line to draw longer? It's very subtle at the moment.

Comment: So your document has more than one instance of the following code: `<line class="line__svg" id="line"` ? (IDs should be unique in a document)

Comment: since we have no context for what these different php files are, whether they are executed separately, or one is included within the other to form a single page, whether you've included the relevant JS and HTML code in them, when/how you're executing the code, whether you see any console errors etc etc etc, it's very hard to help. Your code above is ok as a summary but doesn't allow us to actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: if you mean you've got the same ID included twice in the same final HTML document, then no it will never work because you can't have duplicate IDs. An ID must uniquely identify an element...otherwise by definition it's no longer an _ID_! The code will only ever select the first element it finds with that ID. All others are considered to be invalid. If you want the code to be able to target more than one element you'll have to redesign it to use classes instead of IDs (then the elements can share a class in common), or to pass the function the ID of the specific element you want to act on.

Answer (score 2):

That's how IDs work. You only can have one instance of an Id (kind of - there are tricks but you don't want to do that).

Instead use classes...

```
<tagName class="line">
```

...and loop over it:

```
// Selecting all lines
const scrollLineCollection = document.querySelectorAll(".line");

for ( const scrollLine of scrollLineCollection ) {
  // do something with scrollLine
}
```